# What is the difference between smartphone cover and case?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Recently I read some blogs regarding protection of smartphones. Some blogs have mentioned smartphone covers and some have talked about cases. If we go through [Apple](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/iphone/iphone-accessories/cases-protection)'s official site, it shows only iPhone cases and NOT iPhone covers. [Here](http://www.otterbox.com/en-us/search?q=iPhone%20covers), the main title is 'iPhone covers' and they have written 'case' everywhere that makes me confused.

To my mind, covers are used to cover the entire smartphone, but have a little or no role in its protection, while cases can protect smartphones even if they don't cover them.

Smartphone cover:
[image: sleeve that covers the entire phone]

Smartphone case:
[image: case that protects just the edges and back]

My questions are:
1. My assumption regarding cover and case is right or wrong?
2. At times, people write cover for case and vice versa, so are they interchangeable words?
3. Flip cover or back cover can be said Flip case or back case?
4. Is it ok to say the smartphone cover a skin or a sleeve? Does it cover only the screen or the entire smartphone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they can be used interchangeably. However:

- Most people would think of your second picture when they hear the word "case": that is, a "case" is a protective casing for the phone that does not necessarily cover the entire phone, and that stays on while you use it.
- Most people would call your first picture a phone "sleeve": something you slide the phone into, but take off when you're actually using the phone.
- "Phone cover" seems less common. Most people seem to default to calling "a thing they put on their phone" a case.

Flip case or flip cover are also interchangeable--they both mean this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Case is something which is used to put something else inside it.**
*We use a case to put in glasses. The case protects our glasses.*

**Cover is something which is used to hide something.**
*We use a lens cover to protect lenses. Here too, cover protects our glasses.*

I think both the words can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Cases are usually hard and will retain their shape well without the smartphone in them. Covers, on the other hand will most likely be soft and will not retain their shape as well as cases without the device in them.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand case is a protective sheath to safeguard damage through accidental fall and covers the back of the phone only. Phone can function as it is. But covers are a flip cover or a wallet like pouch to hold the phone not protective but hides the phone. It cant be used as-is but flip it open or take out and use.

Comment: A case isn't *necessarily* open. A guitar case, for example, doesn't allow you to play the guitar while it's in the case.

Answer (score -1):

As of my knowledge Smartphone cover will cover entire phone and will hides the mobile phone.The Phone case will cover expect screen entaire thing will be covers.Both are protects the phone by damages.